# Send an email that was redirected to a mailbox on the server (Exchange server)

Tags: email, active-directory, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have opened a centralized mailbox that collects all the emails that come to my organization (for analysis).
This is done by a Transport Rule that i created which redirects all the email to this mailbox.

The problem is that when i tried to send it back to the original recipients with the EWS application it gives me this error:
`ErrorSendAsDenied -
The user account which was used to submit this request does not have the right to send mail on behalf of the specified sending account., Cannot submit message.`

This email was sent from outside of the organization so I guess i should grant the centrailzied  mailbox SEND-AS permissions for the external email.

I have looked at the Add-ADPermission cmdlet here: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124403%28v=exchg.160%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

And tried to grant the mailbox permissions to "NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON" but it doesn't recognize it,
How can grant the permissions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to resend the message as the original sender unless you own that sender domain and that is an authoritative domain (eg you can then assign rights to send as the security principal that owns that email address). Otherwise what your doing is considered spoofing and will be disallowed in the client API's for security reasons. You also don't wan't to just resend a message like that anyway eg if it has external recipients and you just resent it to all the recipients it you will be sending another copy to those external recipients in that case (which will mostly likely then just get bounced for spf reasons). What you need to know is the envelope recipients of the original message and just resend to those recipients.

A few workarounds for this would be to use the replay directory on Transport server https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124230(v=exchg.150).aspx this would be the most common method as it allows you control the delivery via Xheaders (eg so you can restrict which recipients get the message your resending) and gives the most flexibility but requires file level access to the Transport Server. Other EWS methods would be to look at using Moderation instead and then release the approved the messages,